# How can I get a user's city location in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm tying to get a user's location( just the user's city location) I am await of the plugin geolocation in flutter and I want to know if there's a way I can get just the user's city location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to geocode the coordinates given by your plugin

To do that, there is another plugin like [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) which provides both features :

- **Get the current location of the device**
- **Translate an address to geocoordinates and vice verse**

The geocoding part can be find [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#geocoding)

Comment: Starting from version 6.0.0 the geocoding features (placemarkFromAddress and placemarkFromCoordinates) are no longer part of the geolocator plugin. They have moved these features to their own plugin: geocoding -> https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding